# Index page refresh when logged-in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, page-refresh

I have an index.php page, which behaves as follows :

- if a session var exists and is set, it displays a menu + some info
  about the user (userID, IP adress, link to disconnect)
- if the session var is not set, it displays a login form

So if you go there for the first time, you'll see the login form.

When the user provides his login+password, there is an AJAX call to login_check.php. The main purpose of this page is to generate a session variable (if the user info meets several requirements), but it also sends error messages back to the bottom of the form (under the form of JSON var) in case of authentification failure.

Here is its core :

login_check.php

```
if (authentification($login, $password)) {

            //creates the session variable
            $_SESSION['auth'] = $login; 

           //? here I'd like to refresh the index page 

        }
    else {
        //the error that will be displayed at the bottom of the form
        $json_err .= "Incorrect login or password";

    }
```

index.php looks like this :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
    //the menu is displayed, because the user is looged-in
}
else {
    //the login form is displayed, because the user is not authentificated
}
```

So far, I have to manually refresh the index page so that it takes the session var into account. Is there a way to do it automatically ?

Solutions like "location.reload" are not really suitable, because of the error messages that might be displayed. I also tried to call again index.php from login_check.php using "include" or "header" but it didn't work.

Should I make a conditional refresh within my jQuery function, depending on what data was sent back by login_check.php ?

What would you advice ?

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: tried to make it more accurate, see my edit. Thanks :)

Comment: I finally chose to make a conditional refresh with jQuery, within the AJAX call : 

`if ((data.succ)=="success") {
      window.location.reload();
     };`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to eun your checklogged.php for example once every 5 min and if user if not logged redirect to login page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    getStatus();
});
function getStatus() {
    $status = $('#islogged').load('login_check.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",50000);
}
</script>
```